# marge swipe button with Google map markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps, button, swipe

I have a google map with markers, I wanted to intergrade it with ebanx
/swipe-button but When I try to swipe the button I get the following error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ebanx.swipebtn.SwipeButton.setOnStateChangeListener(com.ebanx.swipebtn.OnStateChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Bellow is my Code
MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private List<LocationModel> mListMarker = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        getAllDataLocationLatLng();

        swipe(); // I call it from here

    }

    
    private void getAllDataLocationLatLng(){
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Menampilkan data marker ..");
        dialog.show();

        ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
        Call<ListLocationModel> call = apiService.getAllLocation();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListLocationModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ListLocationModel> call, Response<ListLocationModel> response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                mListMarker = response.body().getmData();
                initMarker(mListMarker);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ListLocationModel> call, Throwable t) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    private void initMarker(List<LocationModel> listData){
         
        for (int i=0; i<mListMarker.size(); i++){
             
            LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(i).getLatutide()), Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(i).getLongitude()));
            
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(mListMarker.get(i).getImageLocationName()));
            
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(0).getLatutide()), Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(0).getLongitude()));
            
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude), 11.0f));
        }
       

    }
//ebanx /swipe-button code
    private void swipe(){

        SwipeButton swipeButton = (SwipeButton)findViewById(R.id.swipe_button);
        swipeButton.setOnStateChangeListener(new OnStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChange(boolean active) {
                /*
                More code here*/
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity_Maps.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <com.ebanx.swipebtn.SwipeButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:inner_text_background="@drawable/inner_text_shape"
        app:button_image_disabled="@drawable/ic_lock_open_black_24dp"
        app:button_image_enabled="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
        app:button_background="@drawable/shape_button2"
        app:inner_text="Swipe to Unlock"
        app:inner_text_size="20sp"
        app:inner_text_bottom_padding="15dp"
        app:inner_text_top_padding="15dp"
        app:button_top_padding="15dp"
        app:button_right_padding="15dp"
        app:button_bottom_padding="15dp"
        app:button_left_padding="15dp"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish here but move your `findViewById(R.id.swipe_button)` to the `onCreate()` method and declare `swipeButton` in your activity so you can access it on your swipe() method

Comment: @javdromero I've Inserted an image to elaborate my accomplishment

Comment: In your xml, your SwipeButton needs an id, in this case you are refering to R.id.swipe_button

Comment: @javdromero I don't know how I missed ``` android:id="@+id/swipe_button" ``` but actually I did all what u told me and actually it worked! thanks